# Get the BQ Query History Data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running the following query in my BQ console to see the query history data:

```
select * from  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT;
```

I can see the all the data query data present in the results. I came across Audit Logs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs

I have created the sink using command:

```
gcloud logging sinks create bq-audit-sink pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/topics/bq_audit  --log-filter='protoPayload.metadata."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata
```

But i am not able to find the query data i.e past query which is fired and the information about the job.
How to get the data is which we can get via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` view.

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA table is a historical record, the log sync receives events when they flow through the log mechanism.  The sink doesn't get backfilled with events from before the sink was setup, if that was your hope.

Are you not receiving any events in the pubsub topic?  Try running a query in the instrumented project and observe what's emitted into the pubsub topic.

Comment: Method name as `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.Query` will give me the required results

Comment: Depending on invocation, you may also want to look for events related to `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob`, as BQ supports two entrypoints for inserting query work.